# Why is this while loop skipped in javascript?

Tags: javascript, while-loop

In both conditions the while loop should evaluate to true.
The loop variable is variable is set to be less than `h` and greater than zero.

```
function snailClimb(){
var h = 6;
var u = 3;
var d = 1;
var f = 10;
var result = 0;
var dayTravel;
var container = [];
var initialDay = u - d;
container.push(initialDay);
var travel = u;
var totalDistance;
totalDistance = container.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr ); 
while( totalDistance < h && totalDistance > 0) { // BEFORE IT WAS || instead of &&

    dayTravel = travel - (travel * (f/100));
    if (dayTravel !== 0){
    container.push(dayTravel);
    }
    travel = dayTravel;
    container.push(-d);
    result++;
    totalDistance = container.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr ); // this was added as well.

}

console.log(totalDistance);
console.log(result);
}

snailClimb();
```

Comment: `totalDistance` is never updated inside the loop so once it enters the condition will always stay true

Comment: Thanks Bassie. I tried that but then the entire while loop gets skipped.

Comment: @Jacks How can changing code *inside* the loop prevent it from being entered?  If you didn't change code inside the loop, you didn't "try" what Bassie is talking about.

Comment: You can't JUST evaluate `totalDistance` inside the loop; you still have to do it before, but *also* inside.

Comment: Please don't change the logic of the question after people have started to answer. All the answers below now does not make any sense at all and people who encounter while loop being skipped in the future will be very confused with the accepted answer. Remember, SO is not a forum. It is a database of solutions to programming problems. You are not merely asking us to solve your problem. You are formulating a programming problem to help other people get answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two reasons why this is an infinite loop.

1. You never update `totalDistance`. In the code `totalDistance` is the same value thus if it's true the first time it will always be true.
2. Consider the logic of your `while` condition:

   while (totalDistance < 6 || totalDistance > 0) { ...

If `totalDistance` is more than 6 (the value of `h`) then it will evaluate to:

```
while (false || true) ...
```

Which is the same as: `while (true) ..`

If `totalDistance` is less than 0 then it will evaluate to:

```
while (true || false ) ...
```

which is the same as `while (true) ..`

If `totalDistance` is between 6 and 0 then it will evaluate to:

```
while (true || true) ...
```

So as you can see, there is no condition where the while loop will terminate.

What you probably want is:

```
while (totalDistance < h && totalDistance > 0) { ...
```

The English language is unfortunately very lazy about its logical usage of `and` and `or`. In English it's perfectly normal for people to use the word `or` when they mean logical `and`. Be very careful of thinking in English. When programming you need to think Methamatically.

Answer (score 3):

`totalDistance` never changes inside the loop. Therefore, the condition `totalDistance < h || totalDistance > 0` will never have a different evaluation.

Comment: @Jacks: That is impossible; in order to execute the code that was changed, the loop had to have been entered.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop checks the values `totalDistance` and `h`.

However your loop only updates `dayTravel`, `container`, `travel`, `result`.

You need to update `totalDistance` or `h` to exit the loop (due to the `||` you need to update `totalDistance`, really).

Answer (score 0):

> The loop variable is variable is set to be less than `h` **and** greater than zero.

Ugh... then why on Earth did you write this?:

```
while( totalDistance < h || totalDistance > 0) {
```

Wouldn't *this* make more sense?

```
while (totalDistance < h && totalDistance > 0) {
```

That aside, you are evaluating `totalDistance` and `h` in order to get in the loop, but they are never even touched inside of it. Of course the result will be either an infinite loop or a no-op. "Not big surprise", said the Heavy.

My suggestion? Go back to the draft or diagram (in case you have any) and think again about what variables you need and how will use use them. This is a mess, and as far as I know, that's the only way to fix it. At least that's what worked when I had to fix *my own* mess back when I was starting with things.

Don't worry too much, though. With some more attempts I'm sure you should be able to code what you really intend to do. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

To acheive expected result , use below option

1.Important thing to remember using 'while' is to make sure that there is some parameter which make its condition false

2.Modified the condition such that evaluates result to h and executes the while loop successfully

while( result < h)

```
JS:

    function snailClimb(){
    var h = 6;
    var u = 3;
    var d = 1;
    var f = 10;
    var result=0;
    var dayTravel;
    var container = [];
    var initialDay = u - d;
    container.push(initialDay);
    var travel = u;
    var totalDistance=0;

      while( result < h) {

        dayTravel = travel - (travel * (f/100));
        if (dayTravel !== 0){
        container.push(dayTravel);
        }
        travel = dayTravel;
        container.push(-d);
        result++;
        totalDistance = container.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr );
    }


    console.log("total Distance",totalDistance);
    console.log("result", result + 1);
    }

    snailClimb();
```

codepen url for reference- https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/RVVLvd